# IBAction in UIScrollview > Subview

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, uiscrollview, subview

Really hope u can help me! I have a strange problem with Subviews. I'm trying to do a simple IBAction in one of my Subviews but as soon as i click my button, it gives me some memory error. I tried to add it to a property and synthesize the button.

I got one scrollview for horizontal scrolling, added a subview for vertical scrolling, the second subview holds a viewcontroller where my button stands.

If i click that button i get a BAD ACCESS error. NSZombie gives me this error:

> 2012-04-05 14:26:06.924 SlideAppTest[44978:f803] ***
>   -[SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6c4bfe0

This is my code:

// RootSlideHoofdstuk3.h (vertical scroll)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootSlideHoofdstuk3 : UIViewController
<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

// RootSlideHoofdstuk3.m (vertical scroll)

```
#import "RootSlideHoofdstuk3.h"
#import "SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3.h"

@implementation RootSlideHoofdstuk3
@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width,_scrollView.frame.size.height);
    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;    
    _scrollView.bounces = NO;
    _scrollView.delegate = self;

    SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 *subslide1 = [[SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    subslide1.view.frame = frame;
    [_scrollView addSubview:subslide1.view]; 
}
```

// SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3.h (Slide viewcontroller)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3 : UIViewController {
    UIButton *button;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

@end
```

// SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3.m (Slide viewcontroller)

```
#import "SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3.h"

@implementation SubSlide1Hoofdstuk3
@synthesize button = _button;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(IBAction)buttonActie {
    NSLog(@"Button clicked!");
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Try This : 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i still get the same error :(

Comment: I added my example project, if you have to take a quick look, would be great! Thanks

Comment: I am looking into your code, it is downloading......

Comment: Hey Dude, Congrats..:) Uploading the code....!!!

Comment: Wow! Nice mate, big big BIG thanks to you! Hehe, could u describe what u did, so i can confirm your answer and give credit!

Comment: O and btw, could u delete the link in the comment? I just saw that my images and stuff are included in the file! But thanks again, nice work!!

Comment: Hey, There are two catches, first you have just allocated memory to your SubSlides and you have not initialized them,
Second is the buttonclick method's target you have created to  SubSlidesViewController and there views and subview of your SlideView. That is some how not able to respond to your touches. 
And by the way it is not about credit it is about help...!!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem isn't in the UIButton, but the UIScrollView.  You have the property declared as weak, it should be strong (or retain if you are not trying to use ARC)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried both options, strong and the retain option, both options didn't work.. I update my post with a project file, maby you could take a quick look at whats going wrong here? Would be great!